# Calling a 3rd party .NET DLL using JNI

Tags: java, .net, dll, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call a 3rd party .NET DLL (Taken from [here](https://github.com/TheCodeKing/XDMessaging.Net)) from within a JAVA program.
After looking [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13093/C-method-calls-within-a-Java-program) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2876/JNI-Basics-1/?fid=4729&df=90&mpp=50&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=51#xx0xx) I managed to get the whole thing to compile and run. But I get an exception when running the .NET code:

> fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

This only happens when I try to access another .net object and method from within the .NET DLL:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_broadcast
(JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
   // Instantiate the MC++ class.
   IManagedWrapper* t = IManagedWrapper::CreateInstance();

   // The actual call is made. 
   t->Broadcast();
}

void ManagedWrapper::Broadcast(std::string message)
{
   //Uncommenting the following line will raise the error
   //IXDBroadcast^ broadcast = XDBroadcast::CreateBroadcast(XDTransportMode::WindowsMessaging);
}
```

I managed to create a .NET DLL that links to the above code and works as desired.

How can I call the .NET objects and method from the Java code?

Comment: Google has shown me: [JNI4NET](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) and [Calling .Net Dlls from Java code without using regasm.exe](http://codefry.blogspot.com/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html). It will likely show you more solutions if you desire and persevere.

Comment: Thanks! I looked for 2 days before posting here but I never encountered the 2nd link you posted. That did the trick!

Comment: I wonder if anyone has the code from the 2nd link that @HovercraftFullOfEels referenced - it is gone from the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finnaly followed @"Hovercraft Full Of Eels" link in the comments:
[Calling .Net Dlls from Java code without using regasm.exe](http://codefry.blogspot.com/2012/01/calling-net-dlls-from-java-code-without.html)

I used C++\CLI to bridge between the native and managed code and it worked beautifully.
The main issue was that my bridge DLL runs under JVM, and the DLL I tried to load wasn't in JRE\bin directory. To overcome this problem I loaded the .Net assemblies dynamically from C++/CLI code (Based on [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908/en-us)):

```
static Assembly^ MyResolveEventHandler( Object^ sender, ResolveEventArgs^ args )
{
    //Retrieve the list of referenced assemblies in an array of AssemblyName.
    Assembly^ MyAssembly;
    Assembly^ objExecutingAssemblies;
    String^ strTempAssmbPath = "";

    objExecutingAssemblies = Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly();
    array<AssemblyName ^>^ arrReferencedAssmbNames = objExecutingAssemblies->GetReferencedAssemblies();

    //Loop through the array of referenced assembly names.
    for each (AssemblyName^ strAssmbName in arrReferencedAssmbNames)
    {
        //Check for the assembly names that have raised the "AssemblyResolve" event.
        if (strAssmbName->FullName->Substring(0, strAssmbName->FullName->IndexOf(",")) == args->Name->Substring(0, args->Name->IndexOf(",")))
        {
            //Build the path of the assembly from where it has to be loaded.                
            strTempAssmbPath = pathBase + args->Name->Substring(0, args->Name->IndexOf(",")) + ".dll";
            break;
        }

    }
    //Load the assembly from the specified path.                    
    MyAssembly = Assembly::LoadFrom(strTempAssmbPath);

    //Return the loaded assembly.
    return MyAssembly;
}
```

Comment: I have the same exact situation (JVM to DLL via JNI, then C++ tries to use a managed C# DLL and fails) but I never get a callback from the `AssemblyResolve` event.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what native Java to .NET Bridges are doing in the background.

Depending on amount of .NET code you need to use and complexity of your .NET object (what kind of methods you have, if you use generics, if you have arrays etc...) you could consider also using such bridge. When you dig into such case deeper then one after another more limitations are coming up if you do it manually through C++/CLI yourself. If you need quick reliable solution for production environment I would recommend to check:

- [Javonet](http://www.javonet.com)
- [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com)
- [JNI4NET](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net)

Each of these Bridges will cover all native communication for you and delivery very easy interface to use .NET load any DLL and even use the whole .NET Framework in your JAVA application.

Depending on your needs, **Javonet** I think is the easiest and very light one with huge power and flexibility, definetly usefull if you look for reliable commercial solution with good support and easy API to get things done in 5min (for non-commercial and academic is free). **JNBridge** more havy with strongly typed proxy classes generator also very powerfull and also good for commercial usage especially if you need any of their dedicated connectors (affects price but depends on your needs). **JNI4NET** nice open-source project I would say for non-critical, non-commercial applience but worth to check.

With such bridge you do not care about any additional implementation, just copy .NET dll and use it in JAVA. You can see it here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6XfzrHTdK4