# Call from Java code to .net DLL through JNI not returning

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I wrote a JNI wrapper for .net DLL file (DLL has been updated accordingly) but the solution stucks as soon as the call to dll function is made.

I have a .net dll which is used to access SecuGen Fingerprint scanner. It is working fine when used in a .net project. 
Now I want to use it in a JAVA project. I have updated the dll file according to the JNI requirements. It is not returning once the function in a dll has bee called that is the control leaves JVM and hence i cant debug what is wrong or happening.
Edit: I have finally been able to call one of function from dll (a simpler one). But still when i call the CaptureImage it just hangs.

Comment: Attach a .NET or native debugger and find out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a 3rd party .NET DLL using JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062836/calling-a-3rd-party-net-dll-using-jni)

Comment: I tried debugging the code itself and dump the threads. It seems the threads are waiting for response from the dll file.

Comment: @yms no result is being returned from dll. I'm not getting any exception.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do will not work. 
.net DLLs cannot be used directly from Java with JNI. JNI can only load native DLLs.

You need a "bridge" dll, or library, meaning a native dll that loads the .net stuff for you. Then you use that native dll from JNI.

Take a look at this open source project:
[JNI4Net: bridge between Java and .NET (intraprocess, fast, object oriented, open-source)](http://jni4net.com/)

It seems to do what you need.

Comment: 1. I rebuild my dll using JNI specifications. For example making the java class, getting its header file and using that to create functions in C++ and converting it to dll.
2. Does jni4net wokrks with c++ dlls as well? Also my dll uses 2 other dlls :), will it cater that also?